# why does deleting a database fail when using cnosdb？

Tags: cnosdb

This is the cnosdb version I used:
cnosdb 2.4.0, revision b9a0519cf5dade47e953e613ab30a334e497c62c

I start a 3+2 cluster and create a database with the following statement:

create database db1;

kill a data node and see that deleting the database failed:
[image]

Why does the kill node affect the drop operation?